# Match a row with a date that is between 2 dates in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a query that calculates whether the correct booking fee was charged for all bookings. The structure of the tables are below. Please note that due to the environment I am working in I cannot create any stored procedures or functions to help me.

BOOKINGS

```
Date date,
CustomerId int,
BookingTypeId int,
FeeCharged money
```

FEES

```
BookingTypeId int,
FeeAmount money,
EffectiveFrom date
```

Given the example data set below how do I query the data to ensure the fee charged per booking matches the correct fee in the fees table based on the effective from date:
[image: example data]

Comment: How about `Select case when b.FeeCharge=f.FeeAmount && b.Date>=f.EffectiveFrom then 1 else 0 end as FeeValidationStatus from Bookings b left join Fees f on f.BookingTypeId = b.BookingTypeId where <your date range/between condition>`. Now for all the values having `0` are the ones where fees were not changed as per schedule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
WITH
Fees (BookingTypeId, FeeAmount, EffectiveFrom) AS (
    SELECT 1, 50, '2019-06-01'
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, 55, '2019-09-01'
),
Bookings (Date, CustomerId, BookingTypeId, FeeCharged) AS (
    SELECT '2019-07-01', 1, 1, 50
    UNION ALL SELECT '2019-07-02', 1, 1, 50
    UNION ALL SELECT '2019-10-01', 1, 1, 150
),
BookingFeeUpdate as (
    SELECT
        Bookings.BookingTypeId,
        Bookings.Date,
        MAX(EffectiveFrom) LastFeeUpdate
    FROM
        Bookings
    LEFT JOIN Fees ON
        Fees.BookingTypeId = Bookings.BookingTypeId
        AND Fees.EffectiveFrom <= Bookings.Date
    GROUP BY
        Bookings.BookingTypeId,
        Bookings.Date
)
SELECT
    Bookings.*, Fees.FeeAmount as CorrectFee, Fees.EffectiveFrom, case Fees.FeeAmount when FeeCharged then 1 else 0 end Correct
FROM
    Bookings
INNER JOIN BookingFeeUpdate ON
    BookingFeeUpdate.BookingTypeId = Bookings.BookingTypeId
    AND BookingFeeUpdate.Date = Bookings.Date
LEFT JOIN Fees ON
    Fees.BookingTypeId = Bookings.BookingTypeId
    AND Fees.EffectiveFrom = BookingFeeUpdate.LastFeeUpdate
--WHERE Fees.FeeAmount <> Bookings.FeeCharged
```

Comment: @LaraWilson, it's good that you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too.